# How to Find Connection Details to HiveServer2 for Tableau Visualization

Tags: tableau-api, hue, hiveserver2

I am working from the Hue Editor (https://demo.gethue.com/hue/accounts/login?next=/) and I want to connect to Tableau for visualizations.

However, there is no place within the GUI where I can simply copy and paste connection details.

How can I find the connection details in order to allow Tableau to connect to these databases?

Tableau is requesting the following details:

Server

Port

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a connection DSN in ODBC. You need to get/install the odbc driver for that first. Once your odbc is set to the Hive DB, then you can connect to it using Tableau Desktop tool.
But i am not sure if you can connect to impala hue version because you dont know the DB host, port info.

[image]